# Why villager-farmer plants unrelated crops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a carrot farm with **only** carrots.
I want my farmer to grow only carrots, but he randomly plants beetroot and wheat. Why/how is is villager doing this? There have to be only carrots.

I checked every single block and removed all plants which were not carrots and it was 100% a carrot farm, but some days later I found that 30% of my farm is beetroot and wheat again. Why?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because the villager has wheat and beetroot seeds in his inventory. There are a few ways to solve this.

1. Mine the false crops instead so he cant get the seeds. The villager will then plant the seeds in the empty farmland and if you continue this act he will eventually run out.
2. If that doesn't work or if you don't have the time to do so kill the villager and get a new one.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Dabbingsdednow is right. My suggestion is to isolate a new villager, introduce him to the compactor so he becomes a new farmer. He is less likely to have anything in his inventory, so you can use him right away.

Comment: Hey this looks like a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade! Please only post an answer if your answer has something new or different to answer the question (or to point out if the other answer is wrong). Just saying another answer is right should not be posted as an answer, but as a comment to that answer, and then complement it with an upvote. Have a nice day and see you around!

Comment: It is different in that he suggested killing the villager. There is no need to do that.

Comment: Introduce him to what?